# Comparing two string arrays in java using string.equals

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a method that works fine and gives desired result. Here is it's code:

```
public class arraycomparison {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/Users/esna786/File1.txt"));
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/Users/esna786/File2.txt"));
        List<String> File1Content = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> File2Content = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> commonWords = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Getting the contents of File1
        while (sc1.hasNext()) {
            File1Content.add(sc1.next());
        }
        String arr1[] = File1Content.toArray(new String[File1Content.size()]);

        //Getting the contents of File1
        while (sc2.hasNext()) {
            File2Content.add(sc2.next());
        }
        String arr2[] = File2Content.toArray(new String[File2Content.size()]);

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[i].equals(arr2[j])) {
                    commonWords.add(arr1[i]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        String[] comWords = commonWords.toArray(new String[commonWords.size()]);

        System.out.println("Total Number of Common Words are: "+comWords.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < comWords.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + 1 + ": " + comWords[i]);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

it's out put is,

```
Total Number of Common Words are: 7
1: apple
2: ball
3: cat
4: duck
5: elephant
6: fan
7: goat
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Using the same files when I run the program code below almost same as above:

```
//Counting the number of matched words
public int getCommonWords(File File1, File File2) throws IOException {
    try {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(File1));
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(File1));
        List<String> File1Content = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> File2Content = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> commonWords = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Getting the contents of File1
        while (sc1.hasNext()) {
            File1Content.add(sc1.next());
        }
        String arr1[] = File1Content.toArray(new String[File1Content.size()]);

        //Getting the contents of File1
        while (sc2.hasNext()) {
            File2Content.add(sc2.next());
        }
        String arr2[] = File2Content.toArray(new String[File2Content.size()]);

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[i].equals(arr2[j])) {
                    commonWords.add(arr1[i]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        String[] comWords = commonWords.toArray(new String[commonWords.size()]);

        System.out.println("Total Number of Common Words are: " + comWords.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < comWords.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + 1 + ": " + comWords[i]);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it displays following in the output area:

```
run:
Total words of File1.txt are: 11
Total Number of Common Words are: 11
1: apple
2: ball
3: cat
4: duck
5: elephant
6: fan
7: goat
8: a
9: b
10: c
11: d
```

it is even displaying the unmatched words as well, why is it so?
Please help.

Comment: Initialise `commonWords` as the stacktrace indicates...

Comment: I initialized it to null, it should later be occupied with other values in loops.

Comment: Heck no. You initialize it to null, to nothing. You can't assign items to a null array. You're confusing the array with the array items.

Comment: `null` is not an array. `null[i]` produces an `NPE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve your logic and data structures, then use something like:

```
String commonWords[] = new String [Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length)];
```

It's far from perfect, but will allow you to assign values to your array.

Then to print:

```
for(String str : commonWords) {
    if (str != null) {
         System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the null pointer exception for an obvious reason, the variable commonWord is not pointing to an array (you didn't allocate memory for storing the array strings).

```
String commonWords[]=null;
```

You have 2 solutions:

- Use fixed memory allocation:

  ```
  String commonWords[]= new String[Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length)];
  int commonCount = 0;
  ....
  commonWords[commonCount++] = arr2[i]
  ```
- Use dynamic memory allocation:

  ```
  ArrayList<String> commonWords = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
  commonWords.add(arr2[i]);
  ```